# How to use Amazon Connect for voice (java)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

```
        BasicAWSCredentials basicAWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("accessKey", "secretKey");
        AmazonConnectClient amazonConnectClient = (AmazonConnectClient) AmazonConnectClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(basicAWSCredentials)).build();

        Region region = Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1);
        amazonConnectClient.setRegion(region);

        StartOutboundVoiceContactResult voiceContactResult = amazonConnectClient.startOutboundVoiceContact(awsVoiceRequest);
        System.out.println(voiceContactResult.getContactId());
        System.out.println(voiceContactResult.getSdkResponseMetadata().toString());
```

com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to connect to service endpoint:

Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to find a region via the region provider chain. Must provide an explicit region in the builder or setup environment to supply a region.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The `Timeout` would indicate that either an invalid Region was specified (but yours looks fine), or there was no connectivity between the program and the Amazon Connect endpoint. Where is this code being run?